# put request with FindByIdAndUpdate

Tags: mongoose

I know I'm missing something but just can't figure it out, hope you could help. That's my code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const Appointment = require("../models/Appointment");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Appointment.find({}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json();
    } else {
      return res.json(data);
    }
  });
});

router.put("/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const appointment = new Appointment(req.body);

  Appointment.findByIdAndUpdate(id, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json();
    } else {
      return res.json(data);
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

After that I get an error in postman `could not get any response`. My app is running so it's not the problem.

Comment: Did you get any error on your console (server) ? If any, please share

Comment: no i didn't , that's why it makes it harder for me to find the problem lol

Comment: What about `path` that this router is bound to? Could you post your `app.use('somePath', thisRouter)` code fragment?

Comment: You have this code `const appointment = new Appointment(req.body)`, but you don't use appointment  anywhere. Also you didn't set any updated object in  findByIdAndUpdate.